# How To Use Secondary Buildspec file

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have two buildspec files:

1. `buildspec.yml`
2. `buildspectest.yml`

And two Codebuild actions:

```
- Actions:
- ActionTypeId:
    Category: "Build"
    Owner: "AWS"
    Provider: "CodeBuild"
    Version: "1"
  Configuration:
    ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuild
  InputArtifacts:
    - Name: 'SourceArtifact'
  Name: "Build"
  Region: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
  RunOrder: 1

- Actions:
- ActionTypeId:
    Category: "Test"
    Owner: "AWS"
    Provider: "CodeBuild"
    Version: "1"
  Configuration:
    ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuild
  InputArtifacts:
    - Name: 'SourceArtifact'
  Name: "Test"
  Region: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
  RunOrder: 1
```

They are both referenced to the same build project. They both seem to load `buildspec.yml` file. How do I configure my second Codebuild Test action to use `buildspectest.yml` and the first one to use `buildspec.yml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing in both actions the same configuration with `!Ref CodeBuild`. You would have to create two different configurations for the different buildspecs.